# Mixpanel JQL | The paremeter accumulators returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am testing mixpanel, the JQL function.
It looks good, but I think the reduce method doesn't work as expected.

The documentation says:
"A reducer function accepts two arguments: an array of its previous results (accumulators), and an array of items to reduce. The first argument - accumulators - is used to break down the initial set of values into many calls of the reducer function. JQL runs the reduction in a hierarchical fashion, where some subsets of inputs are reduced to accumulator values first, and multiple accumulator values are combined subsequently. There are no guarantees on the order of input."

So I thought ok, *acc* will be [Person1, Person2, ...] but they are all empty did I misunderstand anything?

My Query

```js
function main() {
  return People().reduce((acc, el) => acc)
}
```

[Response from JQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EeBt.png)

```
[
  [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    ...
  ]
]
```

Thanks and have a Great Day